# Retrieving table headers from PHP function using jQuery

Tags: jquery, date

I have a php function called `getDay` which returns the day of the week. That function is the following:

```
    function getDay($value){
        $start_date = date("w");
        $is_now = time();
        $number_of_secs_since_sunday = 86400 * $start_date;
        $result = $is_now - $number_of_secs_since_sunday + (86400 * $value);
        $day = date('Y-m-d', $result);
        return $day;
    }
```

That is then placed into the following PHP loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){  
    echo "<th id='table-header-".$i."'>".getDay($i)."</th>";
}
```

This will return the current days of the week, always starting on Sunday.

Now in my actual `<td>`'s I have a form per `<td>` where the user can submit data. The following is what I currently have:

[image: Screenshot of what the frontend currently looks like]

I would like to use jQuery (because it seems the most straightforward route) to return the table header (aka that specific date) per text field, so that when I submit the text in a text field (ie, going to post.php) the date in the `<th>` will be passed.

For example, if you're in the row **Total Jobs** and the column **2015-07-12** and enter some data in that text field, when you submit the form, the date of **2015-07-12** will be posted to a MySQL database. Not worried about the MySQL part here, just getting the correct table header to be passed to each text field (when that particular form is submitted).

This is what I have currently for the jQuery, but it always returns the first day of the week (in this case 2015-07-12):

```
$('.table').on('click', '.btn-submit', function () {
    var th = $('.table th').eq($(this).index());
    alert(th.text());      
});
```

Any help on the matter is greatly appreciated, as I think I'm making this more difficult than it has to be.

Comment: It would be good if you could post some HTML? What is the `.table` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).index()` refers to the index of `.btn-submit` button but you need the index of the td so `$(this).closest('td').index()` should do it.

```
$('.table').on('click', '.btn-submit', function () {
    var th = $('.table th').eq($(this).closest('td').index());
    alert(th.text());      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are finding index of the button,while you need it for the `<td>`.
Also i am assuming the button and the textbox are in the same `<td>`,since image is not very clear.

So try this,

```
$('.table').on('click', '.btn-submit', function () {
    var th = $('.table th').eq($(this).parent().index());
    alert(th.text());      
});
```